# Как убрать фокус с элемента listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется listbox, элементы которого генерируются динамически.  Необходимо при клике на пустую область listbox'a убирать фокус с элемента.

Comment: Быть может [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116500/deselect-listbox-item-in-c-sharp) отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ListBoxMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
  listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
}
```